# Android Studio "Waiting For Process" only when used with a wearable device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, wear-os

I'm having an incredibly frustrating time using Android Studio with wearable devices.
The problem is that when I try to run or debug the wearable app Android Studio doesn't do anything most of the time, it hangs there with the last message being 
"Waiting for process: com.name of my wearable app".

I can get it to work maybe 10% of the time, then it stops and I might be messing around for 40 minutes before I can get it to work again.

I don't have any issues at all using Android Studio to debug the phone part of the app, its only the wearable part.

Once its stopped working then 1) restarting the watch doesn't fix it, 2) restarting abd doesn't fix it, 3) restarting Android Studio doesn't fix it, 4) manually killing the app process on the watch doesn't fix it. The only thing that will work is to reset the watch. However the entire process of resetting the watch, re-pairing, re-running AS takes about 15 minutes and then afterwards AS will only permit interactive debugging a few times before it stops again. I can't reset the watch everytime AS throws a tantrum, its too time consuming and making my blood pressure rise to dangerous levels.

Something I've frequently noticed is if I try and exit Android Studio it asks: "Do you want to disconnect from the process 'wear'? and if I select the disconnect button then it just sits then and Android Studio never quits.

This is driving me absolutely insane, does anybody please have any experience using the Android Studio debugger with a wearable and has any suggestions how I can some sort of reliability.

Its AS version 1.1.0, using with Lollipop.

Note the wearable app starts/launches/runs perfectly if I'm not using Android Studio, so I don't think there are any issues with the app itself.

******* UPDATE **********
Just updated to AS 1.1.0 today and when trying to debug the wearable it popped up a dialog saying it was unable to open the debugger port
.[image]

[image]

Comment: What device are you using? Don't know if this is the same case, but I've had a ton of problems when using _Debugging over Bluetooth_ with AS/Wear. However, with a direct USB connection (such as on the LG G Watch) it has generally worked fine so far.

Comment: This is with the LG watch using direct USB connection, its got even worse now, I've not been able to interactively debug at all for quite a few days now. I've also got a Moto 360 but wasn't able to get that going at all with BT debugging so gave up with it and used the LG instead as my main development watch. I've also seen some strange behavior with the watch app, which is leading me to suspect sometimes AS and/or adb might be causing the creating of two separate processes on the watch for my app when there should only be one. Have you ever seen any strange or unexplained behavior like that?

Comment: No, I have not experienced those precise issues. Sorry I cannot be more helpful :/

Comment: what version of jdk are you using? Android studio does sometimes not play nice with java 8.

Comment: I've got 6 and 7 installed, but not 8. Just got a new bit of info this morning after updating to the latest AS, there was a message saying the connection was refused opening the debugger ort.

Answer (score 2):

> popped up a dialog saying it was unable to open the debugger port .

Check the port number. It should be same as in `JAVA_OPTIONS` and `AS` Debugger remote configuration under port no.

Comment: The AS remote debugger port is 5005. There's no JAVA_OPTIONS set anywhere that I'm aware of, is JAVA_OPTIONS the same as JAVA_OPTS? (JAVA_OPTS comes up as a google search term when searching for JAVA_OPTIONS). If there was something mismatched about the port, wouldn't the debugger never ever run, as opposed to sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

in command prompt run this :
ping 127.0.0.1:8601
check port 8601 not in firewall list
or used by another program

Comment: It says unresolved host. I must repeat again that sometimes debugging works, but only a small amount of the time, if there was an issue with the port number wouldn't it mean I am unable to debug %100 percent of the time. Not work sometimes and not other times?